# Changing Position Of Lines in C#

Tags: c#

I have two lines in code in c#. Now there is button which changes this lines position to its default location which is shown in below code. Lines are picture box above an image. First here is code:

```
        l1.StartPoint = new Point(5, 5);
        l1.EndPoint = new Point(205, 5);

        l2.StartPoint = new Point(5, 65);
        l2.EndPoint = new Point(205, 65);
```

Now when I press button, l1 line moves to its postion that is shown but l2 line overlaps l1, I mean it changes y axis to 5 instead of 65. So please help me I don't know what is wrong with this, it is very simple.

Comment: There must be something else going on, the code you're showing should work as you want.

Comment: Actually I debugged the code, and when it executes to 3rd line, it shows value of y 5 instead of 65. same for 4th line

Comment: You have to provide more code (xaml of the buttons [if it's wpf]/ c# onclick events). We can't help you with those four lines.

Comment: can you update the code to show how you create an object of l1 & l2 ?